# Proper event binding & Cache jquery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, caching

I have two problems to solve for my website

1. PROPER EVENT BINDING: Consider using the preferred .on() method rather than .click(), .bind(), .hover(), .load(), .ready(), etc.
2. CACHE JQUERY OBJECTS: Please cache the jQuery objects that are used more than once when it's possible, this will help a lot with performance of the site.

Can you help me?

This is my complete script:

```
 /*-----------------------------
              SCRIPTS
  -----------------------------*/

   (function() {
      "use strict";

     /*--------------------------
                LOADER
      --------------------------*/

     $('.page-loading').fadeOut();
     $('.loader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');

     /*--------------------------
                VIDEO
      --------------------------*/

     $("#bgndVideo").YTPlayer();
     $("#bgndVideo-2").YTPlayer();

     /*--------------------------
               ACCORDION
      ---------------------------*/

     $("#accordion1").rlAccordion();

     $("#accordion2").rlAccordion('single', {
        titles: "h3", // html tag parent of minus and plus, this may replaced also for a class
        childNum: 2, // number of the children start open
        open: "&#x2b;", // unicode plus sign
        close: "&#x2212;", // unicode minus sign
     });

     $("#accordion3").rlAccordion('mix', {
        titles: "h3",
        childNum: 2,
        open: "&#x2b;",
        close: "&#x2212;",
     });

     $("#accordion4").rlAccordion('mix', {
        titles: "h3",
        childNum: 4,
        open: "&#x2b;",
        close: "&#x2212;",
     });

     $("#accordion5").rlAccordion('single', {
        titles: "h4",
        childNum: 1,
        open: "&#x2b;",
        close: "&#x2212;",
     });

     $("#accordion6").rlAccordion('mix', {
        titles: "h4",
        childNum: 2,
        open: "&#x2b;",
        close: "&#x2212;",
     });

     $("#accordion7").rlAccordion('mix', {
        titles: "h4",
        childNum: 2,
        open: "&#x2b;",
        close: "&#x2212;",
     });

     $("#accordion8").rlAccordion('mix', {
        titles: "h4",
        childNum: 4,
        open: "&#x2b;",
        close: "&#x2212;",
     });

     /*--------------------------
                  TABS
      ---------------------------*/

     $('#tabs-scale').tabulous({
        effect: 'scale'
     });

     $('#tabs-slide-left').tabulous({
        effect: 'slideLeft'
     });

     $('#tabs-slide-left-2').tabulous({
        effect: 'slideLeft'
     });

     $('#tabs-flip').tabulous({
        effect: 'flip'
     });

     /*--------------------------
             ANIMATED TEXT
      ---------------------------*/

     $('.tlt-adventure').textillate({
        minDisplayTime: 3800,
        in : {
           effect: 'flipInY',
           reverse: false,
        },
        out: {
           delay: 3,
           effect: 'fadeOut'
        },
        loop: true
     });

     $('.tlt-left').textillate({
        minDisplayTime: 1000,
        in : {
           effect: 'flipInY',
           reverse: false,
        },
        out: {
           delay: 3,
           effect: 'fadeOut'
        },
        loop: true
     });

     $('.tlt-right').textillate({
        minDisplayTime: 1000,
        in : {
           effect: 'flipInY',
           reverse: true,
        },
        out: {
           delay: 3,
           effect: 'fadeOut'
        },
        loop: true
     });

     /*--------------------------
             OWL CAROUSEL
      ---------------------------*/

     $('.slide-home').owlCarousel({
        animateIn: 'fadeIn',
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        items: 1,
        rewind: true,
        pagination: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 4000,
        autoplayHoverPause: false,
     });

     $('.slide-home-2').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        rewind: true,
        smartSpeed: 1000,
        pagination: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 4000,
        autoplayHoverPause: false,

     });

     $(".slide-v-l").owlCarousel({
        animateOut: 'slideOutUp',
        animateIn: 'slideInUp',
        items: 1,
        rewind: true,
        smartSpeed: 650,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 4000,
        dots: false,
        mouseDrag: false,
     });

     $(".slide-v-r").owlCarousel({
        animateIn: 'slideOutUp',
        animateOut: 'slideInUp',
        items: 1,
        rewind: true,
        smartSpeed: 650,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 4000,
        dots: false,
        mouseDrag: false,
     });

     $('.slide-h-l').owlCarousel({
        animateIn: 'fadeInLeft',
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        items: 1,
        rewind: true,
        smartSpeed: 650,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 4000,
        dots: false,
        mouseDrag: false,
     });

     $('.slide-h-r').owlCarousel({
        animateIn: 'fadeInRight',
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        items: 1,
        rewind: true,
        smartSpeed: 650,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 4000,
        dots: false,
        mouseDrag: false,
     });

     $('.creative').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        rewind: true,
        smartSpeed: 450,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 3000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        dots: false,
        nav: true,
        navText: [
           "<img src='img/icon/arrow2-left.png'>",
           "<img src='img/icon/arrow2-right.png'>"
        ],
     });

     $('.testimonial').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        rewind: true,
        smartSpeed: 450,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 3000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        nav: false,
     });

     $('.box-slide-1').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        rewind: true,
        smartSpeed: 1000,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 3000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        dots: true,
     });

     $('.box-slide-2').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        rewind: true,
        smartSpeed: 450,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 3000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        nav: false,
     });

     $('.blog-slide').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        rewind: true,
        smartSpeed: 450,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 3000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        dots: false,
        nav: true,
        navText: [
           "<img src='img/icon/arrow2-left.png' width='25' height='25'>",
           "<img src='img/icon/arrow2-right.png' width='25' height='25'>"
        ],
     });

     $('.clients-1').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        items: 5,
        rewind: true,
        smartSpeed: 1000,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 3000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        dots: false,
        nav: false,
        responsive: {
           0: {
              items: 3,
              margin: 10
           },
           480: {
              items: 4,
              margin: 20
           },
           768: {
              items: 5,
              margin: 20
           },
           992: {
              items: 5,
              margin: 50
           },
           1200: {
              items: 5,
              margin: 50
           }
        }
     });

     $('.portfolio-single').owlCarousel({
        items: 2,
        loop: true,
        margin: 40,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 3000,
        rewind: true,
        smartSpeed: 750,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        dots: false,
        nav: true,
        navText: [
           "<img src='img/icon/arrow-left.png' width='40' height='40'>",
           "<img src='img/icon/arrow-right.png' width='40' height='40'>"
        ],
        responsive: {
           0: {
              items: 1
           },
           480: {
              items: 2
           }
        }
     });

     /*--------------------------
             NAVBAR SCROLL
      ---------------------------*/

     $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
           $('.nav-light').addClass('shrink');
        } else {
           $('.nav-light').removeClass('shrink');
        }
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
           $('.nav-dark').addClass('shrink');
        } else {
           $('.nav-dark').removeClass('shrink');
        }
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
           $('.nav-transparent').addClass('shrink');
        } else {
           $('.nav-transparent').removeClass('shrink');
        }
     });

     /*--------------------------
           VALIDOR FORM EMAIL
      ---------------------------*/

     $('#form-contact').validator();
     $('#form-contact').on('submit', function(e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
           var url = "contact.php";
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: url,
              data: $(this).serialize(),
              success: function(data) {
                 var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                 var messageText = data.message;
                 var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                 if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    $('#form-contact').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    $('#form-contact')[0].reset();
                 }
              }
           });
           return false;
        }
     });

     $('#form-comments').validator();
     $('#form-comments').on('submit', function(e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
           var url = "contact.php";
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: url,
              data: $(this).serialize(),
              success: function(data) {
                 var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                 var messageText = data.message;
                 var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                 if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    $('#form-comments').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    $('#form-comments')[0].reset();
                 }
              }
           });
           return false;
        }
     });

     $('#form-newsletter').validator();
     $('#form-newsletter').on('submit', function(e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
           var url = "contact.php";
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: url,
              data: $(this).serialize(),
              success: function(data) {
                 var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                 var messageText = data.message;

                 var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                 if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    $('#form-newsletter').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    $('#form-newsletter')[0].reset();
                 }
              }
           });
           return false;
        }
     });

     /*--------------------------
              SEARCH FORM
      ---------------------------*/

     $('a[href=".form-search"]').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.form-search').addClass('open');
        $('.form-search > form > input[type="search"]').focus();
     });

     $('.form-search, .form-search button.close').on('click keyup', function(event) {
        if (event.target === this || event.target.className === 'close' || event.keyCode === 27) {
           $(this).removeClass('open');
        }
     });

     /*-------------------------- 
           DROPDOWN MENU 
     ---------------------------*/

     $(".dropdown").on('hover', function() {
           $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeIn("fast");
        },
        function() {
           $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeOut("fast");
        });
     $(".dropdown").hover(
        function() {
           $(this).addClass('open');
        },
        function() {
           $(this).removeClass('open');
        });

     /*--------------------------
           SKILL BAR CIRCLE
      ---------------------------*/

     function animateElements() {
           $('.progressbar').each(function() {
              var elementPos = $(this).offset().top;
              var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
              var percent = $(this).find('.circle').attr('data-percent');
              var percentage = parseInt(percent, 10) / parseInt(100, 10);
              var animate = $(this).data('animate');
              if (elementPos < topOfWindow + $(window).height() - 30 && !animate) {
                 $(this).data('animate', true);
                 $(this).find('.circle').circleProgress({
                    startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
                    value: percent / 100,
                    //thickness: 2,/*border radius*/
                    //size: 120,
                    emptyFill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                    //fill: { color: "#fff" } 
                 }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress, stepValue) {
                    $(this).find('div').text((stepValue * 100).toFixed(0) + "%");
                 }).stop();
              }
           });
        }
        // Show animated elements
     animateElements();
     $(window).scroll(animateElements);

     /*--------------------------
              SKILL BAR
      ---------------------------*/

     jQuery('.skillbar').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).appear(function() {
           jQuery(this).find('.count-bar').animate({
              width: jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
           }, 3000);
           var percent = jQuery(this).attr('data-percent');
           jQuery(this).find('.count').html('<span>' + percent + '</span>');
           var t = $(this);

           function perc() {
              var length = t.find('.count-bar').css('width'),
                 perc = Math.round(parseInt(length) / 8),
                 length2 = document.getElementById("skill-item").offsetWidth,
                 perc2 = Math.round(parseInt(length) / parseInt(length2) * 100);
              //t.find('.count').text(perc+'%');
              t.find('.count').text(parseInt(perc2) + '%');
           }
           perc();
           setInterval(perc, 0);
        });
     });

     /*--------------------------
                COUNTER
      ---------------------------*/

     $('.counter').counterUp({
        delay: 50,
        time: 3000
     });

     /*--------------------------
               COUNTDOWN
      ---------------------------*/

     $('.countdown').downCount({
           date: '09/03/2017 12:00:00',
           offset: +10
        },
        function() {
           alert('WOOT WOOT, done!');
        });

     /*--------------------------
            SRCOLL TO TOP
      ---------------------------*/

     var offset = 300,
        offset_opacity = 1200,
        scroll_top_duration = 700,
        $back_to_top = $('.cd-top');

     $(window).on('scroll',function() {
        ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) ?
        $back_to_top.addClass('cd-is-visible'): $back_to_top.removeClass('cd-is-visible cd-fade-out');
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset_opacity) {
           $back_to_top.addClass('cd-fade-out');
        }
     });

     $back_to_top.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('body,html').animate({
           scrollTop: 0,
        }, scroll_top_duration);
     });

     /*--------------------------
            MAGNIFIC POPUP
      ---------------------------*/

     $('.zoom-gallery').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'image',
        closeBtnInside: false,
        mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
        fixedContentPos: false, // fix scrollbar
        image: {
           titleSrc: function(item) {
              return item.el.attr('title') + '<small>by WGA | Umberto</small>';
           }
        },
        gallery: {
           enabled: true
        },
        zoom: {
           enabled: true,
           duration: 500, // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
           easing: 'ease-in-out', // CSS transition easing function
           opener: function(element) {
              return element.find('img');
           }
        }
     });

     $('.flexslider-lightbox').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeBtnInside: false,
        mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
        fixedContentPos: false, // fix scrollbar
        gallery: {
           enabled: true
        }, // this class is for CSS animation below
        zoom: {
           enabled: true,
           duration: 500,
           fixedContentPos: false, // fix scrollbar
           easing: 'ease-in-out',
           opener: function(openerElement) {
              return openerElement.is('img') ? openerElement : openerElement.find('img');
           }
        }
     });

     $('.image-link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom', // this class is for CSS animation belowf
        fixedContentPos: false, // fix scrollbar
        zoom: {
           enabled: true,
           duration: 500,
           easing: 'ease-in-out',
           opener: function(openerElement) {
              return openerElement.is('img') ? openerElement : openerElement.find('img');
           }
        }
     });

     $('.image-link-2').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        removalDelay: 300,
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        fixedContentPos: false, // fix scrollbar
        opener: function(openerElement) {
           return openerElement.is('img') ? openerElement : openerElement.find('img');
        }
     });

     $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
        disableOn: 700,
        type: 'iframe',
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        removalDelay: 160,
        preloader: false,
        fixedContentPos: false // fix scrollbar
     });

     /*--------------------------
             FLEXSLIDER
      ---------------------------*/

     $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: true,
        directionNav: false,
        slideshow: true,
        slideshowSpeed: 2000,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        start: function(slider) {
           $('.flexslider').resize();
        }
     });

     /*--------------------------
          SKROLLR / PARALLAX
      ---------------------------*/

     var s = skrollr.init({
        smoothScrolling: true,
        smoothScrollingDuration: 1500,
        forceHeight: false,
        mobileCheck: function() {
           if ((/Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i).test(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera)) {}
        }
     });

     $('.parallax').jarallax({
        speed: 0.2,
     });

     // for IE //
     if (document.documentMode || /Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // IE or Edge
        $('body').on("mousewheel", function() {
           // remove default behavior
           event.preventDefault();
           //scroll without smoothing
           var wheelDelta = event.wheelDelta;
           var currentScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
           window.scrollTo(0, currentScrollPosition - wheelDelta);
        });
     }

     /*--------------------------
           PARALLAX TEMPLATE
      ---------------------------*/

     $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

     //smoothscroll
     $('.nav-dots-parallax a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function() {
           $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var target = this.hash,
           menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
           'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 2
        }, 500, 'swing', function() {
           window.location.hash = target;
           $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
     });

     function onScroll(event) {
        var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('.nav-dots-parallax a').each(function() {
           var currLink = $(this);
           var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
           if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
              $('.nav-dots-parallax ul li a').removeClass("active");
              currLink.addClass("active");
           } else {
              currLink.removeClass("active");
           }
        });
     }

     /*--------------------------
               ANIMATED
      ---------------------------*/

        new WOW().init();

     })();

     /*--------------------------
               ISOTOPE
     ---------------------------*/

     // portfolio filter
     $(window).on('load', function() {
        'use strict';
        var $portfolio_selectors = $('.portfolio-filter > li > a');
        var $portfolio = $('.portfolio-container');
        $portfolio.isotope({
           itemSelector: '.portfolio-item',
           transitionDuration: '1s',
        });
        $portfolio_selectors.on('click', function() {
           $portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');
           var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
           $portfolio.isotope({
              filter: selector
           });
           return false;
        });

        // blog masonry
        var $blog = $('.blog-masonry');
        $blog.isotope({
           itemSelector: '.blog-item',
           transitionDuration: '1s',
        });
     });
```

Comment: So… you have received feedback/improvement suggestions for your code and now you want to get somebody else to rewrite your code because you have better things to do? Because that's exactly the impression your question makes.

Comment: I don't even see `.click()`, etc. functions in your code, and there are several cached object used already. What exactly do you want us to do? SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: I sent the code just to understand where are the mistakes and do not expect someone to do the work. Thank you

Comment: I just wanted to figure out how to solve the CACHE JQUERY OBJECTS and what they are. This is my first project I create. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call, for example, `$("#accordion1").rlAccordion();` there may be a return (not familiar with whatever library you're using), so you could say `var acc1 = $("#accordion1").rlAccordion();`  That would be my guess as to why the person reviewing your code would say you could cache these, rather than calling them again.  You've a lot of code to wade through, here, though, and I'm not sure whether that would be a needless optimization: if you're never using the accordion again, then there would be no point in declaring a variable to hold that reference.

Comment: Hi, your solution is ok. Look this link:  http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery-standards/. Thanks